# how to customize ~/.history file format in bash and csh

Tags: bash, history, csh

we can custom history command output by  `set history = ( 10 "%T %R\n" )` in  tcsh, and  `export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%T"` in bash.

but ~/.history file format looks like difficult and not clear:

```
#+1475165422
exit
#+1475244355
pwd
#+1475244356
id
#+1519541843
ls -al
#+1519541846
source .cshrc
$: cat ~/.history
```

How to customize ~/.history file in csh and bash?

anybody can help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to alter the format of `~/.history`?

Comment: Setting `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` will always result in the history file containing the epoch timestamp. The contents of `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` determine the format you get to see when using the `history` command; the file itself will always look the same.

Comment: Also, I don't think `%T` is a valid conversion specifier, at least not in Bash.

Comment: `.history` isn't mean to be human-readable; it's an implementation detail of the shell.

Comment: `%T` is short for `%H:%M:%S`.

Comment: Just I said above, ~/.history format is unclear, it is hard to review and not human-readable. I guess since we can change history command output, why cannot change ~/.history file format?